# Django Admin: Getting a QuerySet filtered according to GET string, exactly as seen in the change list?

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

In the Django admin, the user can set filters which limit the rows displayed in the change list. How can I get a QuerySet instance with filters set as defined by the query string? For instance, if I pass ?start_date_gte=2009-11-06, the Django admin will apply a qs.filter(start_date__gte...) somewhere. How can I access such a QuerySet?

I need this since obviously I don't want to rewrite the code that takes these GET parameters and filter()s a QuerySet accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks interesting. However, I was talking about using that QuerySet within the Admin. Found the answer, see below:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
    cl = ChangeList(request, self.model, self.list_display, self.list_display_links, self.list_filter, self.date_hierarchy, self.search_fields, self.list_select_related, self.list_per_page, self.list_editable, self)
    # getting query set with same filters like current change list
    filtered_query_set = cl.get_query_set()
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [django-filter](http://github.com/alex/django-filter).

Answer (score 0):

12 years later :) this right answer has some changes.

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
    cl = ChangeList(
      request,
      self.model,
      self.list_display,
      self.list_display_links,
      self.list_filter,
      self.date_hierarchy,
      self.search_fields,
      self.list_select_related,
      self.list_per_page,
      self.list_max_show_all,
      self.list_editable,
      self,
      self.sortable_by
    )
    # getting query set with same filters like current change list
    filtered_query_set = cl.get_queryset(request)
```