# Django admin MySQL slow INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, django, django-admin

I have a simple model with 3 ForeignKey fields.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    wheel = models.ForeignKey('Wheel', related_name='wheels')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    max_speed = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
    dealer = models.ForeignKey('Dealer')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
```

For the list view in the django admin i get 4 queries. One of them is a SELECT with 3 INNER JOINS. That one query is way to slow. Replacing the INNER JOINs with STRAIGHT_JOIN would fix the issue. Is there a way to patch the admin generated query just before it is evaluated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've implemented a fix for INNER JOIN for Django ORM, it will use STRAIGHT_JOIN in case of ordering with INNER JOINs. I talked to Django core-devs and we decided to do this as a separate backend for now. So you can check it out here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mysql-fix

However, there is one other workaround. Use a snippet from James's answer, but replace select_related with:

```
qs = qs.select_related('').prefetch_related('wheel', 'dealer', 'category')
```

It will cancel INNER JOIN and use 4 separate queries: 1 to fetch cars and 3 others with `car_id` IN (...).

**UPDATE:**
I've found one more workaround. Once you specify null=True in your ForeignKey field, Django will use LEFT OUTER JOINs instead of INNER JOIN. LEFT OUTER JOIN works without performance issues in this case, but you may face other issues that I'm not aware of yet.

Comment: The `select_related('')` didn't work for me, it didn't prevent the inner join from happening. But by specifying `list_select_related = []` in the admin class it did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

You may just specify `list_select_related = ()` to prevent django from using inner join:

```
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_select_related = ()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could overwrite

```
  def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
```

method in your admin class inherited from `ModelAdmin` class

something like this(but this question is rather old):
[Django Admin: Getting a QuerySet filtered according to GET string, exactly as seen in the change list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686934/django-admin-getting-a-queryset-filtered-according-to-get-string-exactly-as-se)

Comment: I have access to the ChangeList.get_query_set but if I patch it with a Car.objects.raw sql query the paginator complains with "'RawQuerySet' has no len()"... I somehow need the queryset in a later stage to patch the sql

Comment: I think you could try to subclass RawQuerySet.

Comment: BTW, have you checked your database indexes? Three joins are not too much.

Comment: Yes, setting up indexes did NOT help

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a way to patch the admin generated Query. It is ugly but it **seems to work**:

```
class CarChangeList(ChangeList):

    def get_results(self, request):
        """Override to patch ORM generated SQL"""
        super(CarChangeList, self).get_results(request)
        original_qs = self.result_list
        sql = str(original_qs.query)
        new_qs = Car.objects.raw(sql.replace('INNER JOIN', 'STRAIGHT_JOIN'))

        def patch_len(self):
           return original_qs.count()
        new_qs.__class__.__len__ = patch_len

        self.result_list = new_qs


class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('wheel', 'max_speed', 'dealer', 'category', 'created')

    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        """Return custom Changelist"""
        return CarChangeList

admin.site.register(Rank, RankAdmin)
```

Comment: The solution doesn't work as you might expect it should. .raw() doesn't do mapping to joined models. In this case it will request data with STRAIGHT_JOIN and will drop all fields that don't exist in the model, and after that it will make separate requests for related fields. Thus there is no benefit in this override.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue in the Django admin (version 1.4.9) where fairly simple admin listing pages were very slow when backed by MySQL.

In my case it was caused by the `ChangeList.get_query_set()` method adding an overly-broad global `select_related()` to the query set if *any* fields in `list_display` were many-to-one relationships. For a proper database (*cough PostgreSQL cough*) this wouldn't be a problem, but it was for MySQL once more than a few joins were triggered this way.

The cleanest solution I found was to replace the global `select_related()` directive with a more targeted one that only joined tables that were really necessary. This was easy enough to do by calling `select_related()` with explicit relationship names.

This approach likely ends up swapping in-database joins for multiple follow-up queries, but if MySQL is choking on the large query many small ones may be faster for you.

Here's what I did, more or less:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList


class CarChangeList(ChangeList):

    def get_query_set(self, request):
        """
        Replace a global select_related() directive added by Django in 
        ChangeList.get_query_set() with a more limited one.
        """
        qs = super(CarChangeList, self).get_query_set(request)
        qs = qs.select_related('wheel')  # Don't join on dealer or category
        return qs


class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

        def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
            return CarChangeList
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had slow admin queries on MySQL and found the easiest solution was to add STRAIGHT_JOIN to the query. I figured out a way to add this to a `QuerySet` rather than being forced to go to `.raw()`, which won't work with the admin, and have open sourced it as part of [`django-mysql`](http://django-mysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/queryset_extensions.html#django_mysql.models.straight_join). You can then just:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(MyAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return qs.straight_join()
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL still has this problem even in version 8 and Django still doesn't allow you to add STRAIGHT_JOIN in the query set. I found a hackish solution to add STRAIGHT_JOIN...:

This was tested with Django 2.1 and MySQL 5.7 / 8.0

```
def fixQuerySet(querySet):
    # complete the SQL with params encapsulated in quotes
    sql, params = querySet.query.sql_with_params()
    newParams = ()
    for param in params:
        if not str(param).startswith("'"):
            if isinstance(param, str):
                param = re.sub("'", "\\'", param)
            newParams = newParams + ("'{}'".format(param),)
        else:
            newParams = newParams + (param,)
    rawQuery = sql % newParams

    # escape the percent used in SQL LIKE statements
    rawQuery = re.sub('%', '%%', rawQuery)

    # replace SELECT with SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
    rawQuery = rawQuery.replace('SELECT', 'SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN')

    return querySet.model.objects.raw(rawQuery)
```

**Important:** This method returns a raw query set so should be called just before consuming the query set