# optimize django admin sql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have the following database structure:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='name')
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', to_field='id', db_column='author_id')


class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    fio = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='fio')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And this Admin class for Book:

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name',)
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'author',)
    readonly_fields = ('id',)
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
```

Everything works fine when It's 500-1000 book records, but on 1-2 million books page freeze for few minutes before shows something. Profiler show me that django join books with authors and then cut last 100 records.

```
SELECT ••• FROM `books` INNER JOIN `authors` ON ( `books`.`author_id` = `authors`.`id` ) ORDER BY `books`.`id` DESC LIMIT 100
```

How can I optimize django to join authors after select books from database? Or use something like that

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY books.id DESC LIMIT 100) t, authors a where t.author_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing a known issue: [Slow INNER JOIN in MySQL can be fixed in Django ORM, but should it?](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22438)

There is a project called [`django-mysql-fix`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mysql-fix) that was started on PyCon 2014 sprints that introduced a custom mysql database backend for fixing `INNER JOIN` issues specifically:

> This project contains optimizations (hacks) for MySQL for Django ORM.
>
> There are two very simple ways to cacth INNER JOIN bug:
>
> - Once you specify field from foreign table in list_display in your Django Admin model;
> - Once you try to sort (order) by field from foreign table.

As far as I understand, under the hood it replaces all `INNER JOIN`s with `STRAIGHT_JOIN`s, quote from [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

> STRAIGHT_JOIN is similar to JOIN, except that the left table is always
>   read before the right table. This can be used for those (few) cases
>   for which the join optimizer puts the tables in the wrong order.

Also see:

- [Django admin MySQL slow INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959083/django-admin-mysql-slow-inner-join)
- [When to use STRAIGHT_JOIN with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512294/when-to-use-straight-join-with-mysql)

Comment: Does this affect postgresql as well?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I'm pretty sure this is mysql-specific. Thanks.